# loop in c++ that keeps track when the count is divisible by 4

Tags: c++

Hello I am having trouble with a c++ program. Basically its a loop that iterates the amount of times the user wants it to. Now when it reaches a number divisible by 4 it keeps track of that number and finally then outputs how many times the number entered was divisible by 4.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int num;
int count;
int test = 0;

int main()
{
    cin>> num;
    for (int count = 0; count < num; count++)
        if (count % 4 == 0)
            (test++);
        else
            cout<<"";  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And you have some code with particular problems??

Comment: I can get it to say how many times it was divisable by 4

Comment: You need to initialize `test` to `0` and to output it before `return 0` in main.

Comment: @user3308486 Might not be relevant for your actual problems, but use  braces (`{}`) as much as possible **for heavens sake**!! Also `cout << test;` after `return 0` is useless!!

Comment: @NemanjaBoric `test`, being declared as a static variable, is automatically initialised. Now this is certainly not good practice but it accidentally works here.

Comment: somehow i have to output test

Comment: @user3308486 Here are some points you should cover in your question: 1) Purpose of your program. 2) Source code of your program. 3) Actual input to your program. 4) Desired output of your program. 5) Actual output of your program. As far as I can tell, you have given us 2) and 5), but 1), 3) and 4) are missing

Comment: @user3308486 _'somehow i have to output test'_ Surely not after returning from `main()` (that's simply not possible!!)

Comment: I'm trying to write a program where the user inputs a number "num" and run a loop from 0 to "num". at that point the The program should tell me whenever the loop counter variable is a multiple of 4, then it should display the number of execptions at the end.

Comment: @user3308486 Commenting on your question doesn't make the question any better. Edit the question instead.

Comment: Why not just divide NUM by 4 and and be done with it?

Answer (score 1):

Well - if you use `return` in `main`, your program will just exit, because that's what return does - ends the function and returns some value. If you want to actually **print** the value of `test`, do it before you `return`:

```
cout << test;
getch(); // use this so the console won't close automatically
return 0;
```

Also, the whole program could be written much better:

```
int main()
{
    cin>> num;
    cout << num/4;
    getch(); // use this so the console won't close automatically
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you *need* to use a loop? If you just need "How many times is a given number divisible by 4" and are not required to loop

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin>> num;
    cout<< num<<" is divisible by 4 "<< (num>>2) <<" time"<<(num>>2>1?"s":"") <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`num>>2` is bit shifting to teh right twice, which is the same as doing an integer divide by 4. It could be replaced by `num/4` if you wanted. Integer division always truncates, so for all positive numbers, it's like rounding down: the same behavior your loop gives you.